# how to remove an image in an Article. OnetoOne association. What should I do in the form?

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I use ->add('file','file') to add an IMAGE associated to an ARTICLE. It works just fine.

But how should I do to remove an IMAGE from the ARTICLE. the form with **file** only allows me to add or change the IMAGE associated with the ARTICLE. No option to simple say: remove the IMAGE.
**how should I do it?**

- Does an option existe in File to add this fonctionality into the form?
- Should I add a new field in ArticleType (mapped' to 'false' because won't be an attribut nor an entity) This field allow user to select a checkbox "remove image". And I process to the remove of the image in the controller when value is set to true?

**I AM MORE ASKING FOR METHODOLOGY RATHER THAN CODE ISSUE, thanks for any help**

THE CODE

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
       ->add('image', new ImageType());
       ->add('removeimage', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'  => 'Remove the image?',
                'mapped' => false,))
  }
}
```

.

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
     $builder
        ->add('file', 'file');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some time for setting up your file uploads then I recommend you  to [Handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) . I have a working project that uses practices, described in this article, and it works really well.

If you want to make "*delete*" button within your form, just follow this simple steps:

first add this lines in your form builder:

```
->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save')) // it's for saving article
->add('delete', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete')) // it's for deleting file
```

then in controller check which button was clicked:

```
if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked()) { // your code here }
```

instead of *your code here* write something like:

```
$article->getImage()->removeUpload();
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

That was it!

Comment: thanks but it doesn't answer my question. I actually do the same way as it is descripble in the link you provided. Not how should I process to delete the image. Or how should I process so that symfoy order the delete of the image

Comment: @Aleqxs, i've edited my answer. it seems to be helpful